# Symfony Validator: validate by comparing the old value from the DB

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-4.4

I'm working with Symfony 4.4,

For security reason, when submitting OrderProduct entity that embedd Product entity, I have to control some values of OrderProduct taken from Product.

So, it's an Symfony API, I receive an orderProduct in a JSON format:

```
{
   "product" : { "id" : 82 },
   "price" : 9.7,
   "quantity": 3,
   //...
}
```

I have to get the product from the database, to test if the price is correct.

## OrderProduct Entity:

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your ProductPriceConstraint and ProductPriceConstraintValidator, make sure you use validator as a service
2. Inject the EntityManager service
3. Query for the product using the id from the value
4. Compare the values

Detailed info on how to create custom constraint validators:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html

Note: Your validator has to be class constraint validator so that you can access every value, not just the price or product property. 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator

Answer (score 0):

I think [custom validation constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html) will be good option. In your custom constraint validator inject `ProductRepository`, find your entity and compare needed values. Maybe create `OrderProduct` validation constraint for your entity and validate a few fields.

```
public function validate($orderProduct, Constraint $constraint)
{
    // a few checks 

    $product = $this->productRepository->find($orderProduct->getProduct()->getId());

    if (!$this->isPriceValid($product->getPrice(), $orderProduct->getPrice()) { 
        $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
            ->atPath('price')
            ->addViolation();
    }

    // ...
}

public function isPriceValid(float $oldPrice, float $newPrice): bool
{
    return $oldPrice === $newPrice;
}
```